Solution of PDE $ \partial_\mu \partial^\mu \delta\phi + V''(\phi) \delta\phi = 0 $ with Fourier transform
The book I am following is Physical Foundations of Cosmology by Mukhanov (p.166).
I have the following equation of motion for some physical field
$$ \partial_\mu \partial^\mu \delta\phi + V''(\phi) \delta\phi = 0 $$
Precisely, there is an arbitrary field $\Phi(\vec{x},t) = \phi(t) + \delta\phi(\vec{x},t) $ and I need to find an expression for fluctuating part $\delta\phi$. There are no given initial or boundary conditions. However, I suppose that, like for most physical fields, the solution vanishes at infinity.
What I managed to do is a transition to the momentum domain, i.e.
$$\partial_t \partial^t \delta\phi(\vec{p},t) + p^2 \delta\phi(\vec{p},t) + V''(\phi)\delta\phi(\vec{p},t) = 0$$
where I used the Minkowski metric and the Fourier transform derivative property. Its solution is
$$\delta\phi(\vec{p},t) = a_+(\vec{p}) \exp(it\sqrt{p^2 + V''}) + a_-(\vec{p}) \exp(-it\sqrt{p^2 + V''})$$
where we make an assumption that integration constants might depend on $\vec{p}$.
And that's my endpoint. It's clear that $$\delta\phi(\vec{x},t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \delta\phi(\vec{p},t) e^{i\vec{p}\vec{x}} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}  [a_+(\vec{p}) e^{it\sqrt{p^2 + V''}} + a_-(\vec{p}) e^{-it\sqrt{p^2 + V''}}] e^{i\vec{p}\vec{x}}$$ but in the textbook it ends up with the following formula $$ \delta\phi = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}(a_p^+ e^{i\omega_pt - i\vec{p}\vec{x}} + a_p^- e^{-i\omega_pt + i\vec{p}\vec{x}}), $$
where $ \omega_p = \sqrt{p^2 + V''(\phi)}$ and $a_p^{+/-}$ are constants.
I have searched through a bunch of PDE examples, though I haven't been able to equate my result with that in the textbook.

I considered it constant since V is a function of the homogeneous part of the initial field while we work with another (inhomogeneous) part of the field. However, I am not sure about it...

Sorry, I wrote $\phi$ to be a function of $\vec{x}$ while as I stated earlier it's a homogeneous part, i.e. same for any point of space, so obviously it's a function of time $t$.

Shouldn't it be $-p^2$ in your differential equation for $\delta\phi(\vec{p}, t)$?

Or is there a minus sign embedded in $\partial_\mu \partial^\mu$?

Yes, $\partial_\mu \partial^\mu = - \partial_\mu \partial_\mu $ when $\mu = 1,2,3$ since we use Minkowski metric

Under the assumption that the mass of the scalar field ($m^2\equiv V''$) is constant, then your solution is correct. To see that its in fact the same as in Mukhanov's book you only need to do some manipulations:
Starting with your expression
$$\delta\phi(\vec{x},t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}  [a_+(\vec{p}) e^{itw_p} + a_-(\vec{p}) e^{-itw_p}] e^{i\vec{p}\vec{x}},$$
and perform a change of variables $\vec{p}\to-\vec{p}$ on the first term we get
$$\delta\phi(\vec{x},t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}  [a_+(-\vec{p}) e^{itw_p-i\vec{p}\cdot \vec{x}} + a_-(\vec{p}) e^{-itw_p + i\vec{p}\cdot \vec{x}}].$$
Now if we define $a_{\vec{p}}^+ = \frac{a_+(-\vec{p})\sqrt{2w_p}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}$ and $a_{\vec{p}}^- = \frac{a_-(\vec{p})\sqrt{2w_p}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}$ then your formula become
$$\delta\phi(\vec{x},t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^{3/2}\sqrt{2w_p}}  [a^+_\vec{p} e^{itw_p-i\vec{p}\cdot \vec{x}} + a^-_\vec{p} e^{-itw_p + i\vec{p}\cdot \vec{x}}],$$
which is exactly what Mukhanov has.
The numerical factors here are arbitrary choices you can make. The factors of $(2\pi)^{3/2}$ basically comes from a choice for the normalization of the Fourier transform (it looks like Mukhanov use the symmetric convention where the transform and the inverse transform both have the same prefactor $1/(2\pi)^{3/2}$) while you start with a convention where you use $1/(2\pi)^3$ and $1$ respectively. The $1/\sqrt{2w_p}$ factor is also arbitrary and mainly chosen to make commutator relations look simpler when we later quantize the field.

Thank You a lot! Indeed, this expression should be quantized further however I expected other reasoning or at least some hidden initial conditions. Typo corrected.
